# ComboBox Select Items

Tags: combobox, javafx

I am trying to select a quantity to add to cart. For example, the drop down list of combo box consists of 1-10 and Others.. If I want to buy more than 10 products, I select the Others.. from drop down list and a text field will be appeared. This is how I set up my comboBox in javaFX:

```
<ComboBox fx:id="qtyComboBox" prefHeight="21.0" prefWidth="159.0" style="-fx-background-color:#D2B48C;" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="4">
      <items>
        <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
          <String fx:value="" />
          <String fx:value="1" />
          <String fx:value="2" />
          <String fx:value="3" />
          <String fx:value="4" />
          <String fx:value="5" />
          <String fx:value="6" />
          <String fx:value="7" />
          <String fx:value="8" />
          <String fx:value="9" />
          <String fx:value="10" />
          <String fx:value="Others.." />
        </FXCollections>
      </items>
    </ComboBox>
```

And this is how I get the selected item from comboBox:

```
if(panel.getQtyComboBox().getValue().equals("Others..")){
        panel.getQtyTextField().setVisible(true);
        qty = Integer.parseInt(panel.getQtyTextField().getText());
    }else{
        qty = Integer.parseInt(panel.getQtyComboBox().getValue());
    }
```

However, when I choose 1-10, it can insert into database without any problem. But when I select the Others.., the text field does not appear. I wonder where did I did wrongly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried, qtyComboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().equals("Others..") ??

Comment: @ShreyasDave Ya but it does not works as well

Comment: @ShreyasDave I wonder do I need the changeListener?